# Intelligent Keyword Searching

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view, taxonomy

I have a taxonomy vocab assigned to a content type in Drupal 6. I've then exposed (using "is one of") it as a field in views which allows a user to search via keywords.

The problem is when it runs the query it is first referencing the term so instead of using a like statement it looks the term up in the taxonomy table and brings back it's ID. So if a user searched for one term that exists and another that doesn't the whole thing fails rather than bringing back relevant results for the first term that exists.

Is there anyway to do partial matching using views?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654099/can-drupals-search-module-search-for-a-substring-partial-search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone looking for the answer the best implementation I could find was Apache Solr.

Relatively easy to setup if you have your own server.

More information can be found here - http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr