# Can Drupal's search module search for a substring? (Partial Search)

Tags: search, drupal, partial, n-gram

Drupal's core search module, only searches for keywords, e.g. "sandwich". Can I make it search with a substring e.g. "sandw" and return my sandwich-results?

Maybe there is a plugin that does that?

Answer (score 2):

Recently I made a [patch](http://drupal.org/node/103548#comment-2727556) for Drupal's core search module to provide it with partial search *(aka n-gram searches)* ability. This is tested against Drupal 6.15 & 6.16 releases. You might want to read about [patching](http://drupal.org/node/60108).

On the other hand you can make use of [Apache Solr Search Integration](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr), [Search Lucene API](http://drupal.org/project/luceneapi) modules or other 3rd-party search solutions which takes more time to implement.

[PorterStemmer](http://drupal.org/project/porterstemmer) module has its own different story in which you might be interested, too.

Answer (score 2):

The most direct module for it is probably [Fuzzy Search](http://drupal.org/project/fuzzysearch). I have not tried it. If you have more advanced search needs on a small to medium sized site, Search Lucene API is a fine solution. For a larger site, or truly advanced needs, Solr is the premiere solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Fuzzy Search (module) does it. https://drupal.org/project/fuzzysearch

Answer (score 0):

[Drupal Finder](http://drupal.org/project/finder) does it somehow, namely: it has an autosuggest feature, so if You start typich `sand` it should suggest You a node containing `sandwich`.